# Continuing an operation if terminal closes

Tags: linux, background-process, nohup, remote-control

I need to execute this command on my terminal, that will operate on a server. I need to modify it such that if I lost the connection and the terminal closes, the operation running is not stopped, continuing the operation until its conclusion.

```
for file in 4458*/payoffTable* ; do cp "$file" /storage/scratch2/id0056/DMM_BASTIAN/M_7/N_15_P_05/Evoluzioni;done &
```

I know there is a command, called "nohup", that allow that, but if I prepend it to the previous command I get an error.
Also, in the case in which some of you is able to give a solution to this problem, I would like to know how to monitor the background processes running on a remote server. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the execution of **nohup** the terminal returns the **PID (Process ID)** that is the process identifier.
By opening a terminal and running the command
    ***ps -ef | grep PID***
the console returns your process created above, if still running. If the process is not returned, it means that the execution is completed.

Comment: Thank you Inian and L. Ionio, now everything is clear.